How to safely label APFS drive in macOS without data loss?
How can I safely label an APFS volume without data loss? I dual-boot macOS and Linux on a Mac Pro and want the Mac disk to be properly labeled in file manager.
I've already renamed the volume in macOS disk utility but the label is not shown in Linux.

Are you talking about the partition label in the GPT?

Is it a known issue that adding a label on an APFS drive in Linux causes data loss?

@Spiff Not sure what it's called.  I mean labels like the ones used in gparted or in Windows.
